# Is an argument copied to the resulting temporary when both the function parameter and return types are references?

Tags: c++

Chapter 6.3.2 of the book C++ Primer says the following:

> The return value is used to initialize a temporary at the call site, and that temporary is the
> result of the function call.

Later, it gives an example for returning reference values with the explanation below:

```
const string &shorterString(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    return s1.size() <= s2.size() ? s1 : s2;
}
```

> The parameters and return type are references to `const string`. The `string`s are not copied
> when the function is called or when the result is returned.

Does this mean that the temporary resulting from this function call is initialized from a reference to the first or the second argument? If so, doesn't that mean that the argument **does** get copied into the temporary?

Comment: There is no temporary returned from this function, it returns a reference.

Comment: Wait, this functional would not return a temporary? So the resulting reference would be used directly in the expression that called the function? For example, `std::cout << shorterString("foo", "bar") << '\n';` would be evaluated as `std::cout << reference to the result of function call << '\n';`?

Comment: The function returns a reference, not a temporary. This reference can be used as an argument to `cout` or `operator<<` just fine.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Oh, I didn't think about the ternary operator. That makes this more interesting.

Comment: @cigien I'm now questioning myself. Feel free to chip in here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63198098/4386278 :)

Comment: This is what happens when bad code formatting happens to good people. The `&` belongs on `string`, not `shorterString`.

Comment: References are syntactic sugar for pointers, with some compile-time restrictions thrown in for "clarity." To really understand this, imagine what would happen if this was done with pointers instead of references.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that the temporary resulting from this function call is initialized from a reference to the first or the second argument?

Yes.

As the logic in the function suggests, wether the temporary is initialized from the first argument or the second argument depends on the value of `s1.size() <= s2.size()`.

> If so, doesn't that mean that the argument does get copied into the temporary?

Yes.

However, it's worth noting that the temporary itself is also a `const string&`. It does not require a copy of a `string` object.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, I don't know how you came to that conclusion but it's an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: Feel free to chip in :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/63198098/4386278

Answer (score 1):

> The return value is used to initialize a temporary at the call site, and that temporary is the result of the function call.

The use of "temporary" is a bit misleading, and as of C++17 - false.

Up until C++17, the function could *theoretically* have created a temporary which is the return value. But the compiler was allowed to skip the creation of such a temporary, and just initialize/construct at the call site, e.g. if you wrote:

```
const std::string& foo { shorterString(my_string1, my_string2) };
```

then `foo` would have been initialized by the code inside shorterString directly (even if the function wasn't inlined). Granted, this doesn't matter all that much for `const std::string&`, but it sure does matter for types whose construction has side-effects; and for types which are non-copyable/non-movable.

Beginning in C++17, this is no longer an "optimization" -  it is *guaranteed* in the standard that no temporary is constructed/initialized. See [this blog post](https://jonasdevlieghere.com/guaranteed-copy-elision/) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: I don't think you can reason about undefined behaviour (dangling references) by invoking the pre-C++17 optimisation opportunities. UB is UB.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I didn't think I reasoned about UB... just about whether or not a temporary object of the return type is created or not (irrespective of what happens with OP's function).

Comment: I see, you're talking about the mechanics of `return`, rather than of the conditional operator. That's reasonable, seeing as it turns out the conditional operator won't create a temporary, though I still haven't worked out _why_ that is.

Comment: What's your intuition for it _creating_ a temporary?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63198098/4386278 for the juicy deets - I'll be glad if you can answer it (ideally, doing so kindly!)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Yours is a very good question (unless one happens to have an encyclopaedic knowledge of the part of the standard about evaluation expressions, in which case it's probably trivial; but that is only for high priests and not for us mortals.)

Comment: Thanks - turns out my misunderstanding was a combination of: (a) the "initialise the result" clause without realising it was conditional on us being in the "result is an rvalue" case (which, in turn, is only entered when the operand types differ), and (b) the remaining wording (that we fall back on instead) in my opinion is not super-explicit so it never stood out to me.

Comment: BTW I don't really like calling mandatory elision an "optimisation" (guaranteed or otherwise) or even "elision", really.. it's just a change in the meaning of code so now there's nothing to elide or optimise. But I realise that's nitpicking ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Doing that used to be an optimization - instead of writing the return value to the `ax` register (on x86), you wrote it to whatever register you assigned the result of the function to at the call site.

Comment: It used to be, yeah. I'm talking about the current situation since C++17 :)

Comment: Oh, to be clear, I wasn't suggesting an edit (I think I'm the only one who thinks this way); just thought it was interesting :) Though the new revision does seem more factually accurate yep