# Doesn't C++ mandate that (cond ? string_1 : string_2) initialize a string?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Considering:

```
void foo(std::string& s);
```

Inside this function, the expression `s` is *lvalue* `std::string` (*not* `std::string&`), because references don't really "exist" in expressions:

> [`[expr.type/1]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1): **If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`”** ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), **the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis**. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression. *[..]*

Now consider:

```
const std::string& foo(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    return (s1.size() < s2.size() ? s1 : s2);
}
```

There was a debate on another question about whether the conditional operator here involves the creation of a temporary (which then has ramifications about the return value for `foo` being a dangling reference).

My interpretation was that, yes, it must, because:

> [`[expr.cond/5]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#5): If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, **the result is of that type and value category** and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

and:

> [`[expr.cond/7.1]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#7.1): The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type and **the result object is initialized using the selected operand**.

Initialising a `std::string` from a `std::string` involves a copy.

However, I was surprised that GCC didn't warn on the dangling reference. Investigating, I found that `foo` indeed *does* propagate the reference semantics for the selected argument:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

void foo(string& s1, string& s2)
{
    auto& s3 = (s1.size() < s2.size() ? s1 : s2);
    s3 = "what";
}

int main()
{
    string s1 = "hello";
    string s2 = "world";
    
    foo(s1, s2);
    
    cout << s1 << ' ' << s2 << '\n';   // Output: hello what
}
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caa9817e1ccc086c))

The original `s2`, passed by reference into `foo`, has been selected by the conditional operator, then bound to `s3`, and modified. There is no evidence of any copying going on.

This doesn't match my reading of how expressions work and of how the conditional operator works.

So, which of my above statements is incorrect, and why?

---

Since there seems to be some confusion, below I have diagrammed what my understanding says is the chain of events. I realise that it's wrong — my testcase above proves that. But I'd like to understand exactly *why*. Ideally I'd like some standard wording, not just "you're wrong". I already know I'm wrong. That's why I'm asking.

1. References to strings passed into function
2. Expression evaluated containing conditional operator

   - The latter two operands are lvalue expressions of type `const std::string` (*not* references!)
   - The latter two operands have the same type and value category, so the conditional operator's result is `const std::string`, too
3. The result of the expression is initialised from the selected operand; we've already established that the operands and the result type are `const std::string`, so it's a `const std::string` initialised from a `const std::string`
4. The expression, as one that initialises an object, has value category rvalue (and I believe this implies the object is also a temporary?)
5. **Then** we initialise the function's return value from that temporary; this is evil as the return type is a reference, so we dangle.

Comment: @Barry Oh, is that term only used for adjusting types in declarations? Okay I'll remove that parenthetical, cheers

Comment: For the same reason it has nothing to do with pointer arithmetic - it's just a totally unrelated thing. Reference collapsing is when you have like `using T = int&;` and then you write `T&`.

Comment: @Barry Never suggested it has anything to do with pointer arithmetic; not sure why it would

Comment: I think @Barry meant, "for the same reason it has nothing to do with pink elephants".

Comment: @cigien Right, but I didn't mention pink elephants either. It was just completely unnecessary snark. Don't know why being nice is so hard...

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought you had misunderstood the comment, that's all :)

Comment: @cigien Not at all :)

Comment: Wouldn't your question be just as relevant for the code `string s1, s2; const string& s (some_cond() ? s1 : s2);` - without the complication of being in a function?

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah, to be fair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My misunderstanding appears to have stemmed from step #3 in my "diagram": the wording I quoted regarding initialising the result (`[expr.cond/7.1]`) doesn't apply; it's under the *"otherwise, the result is a prvalue"* clause. I'd missed that.

So, there is in fact no talk about initialisation with respect to our conditional operator expression here. Thus, no new object being created and, if such an object doesn't exist, it cannot be a temporary.

The only description of what we get back, then, is:

> [`[expr.cond/1]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#1): *[..]* the result of the conditional expression is the value of the second expression, otherwise that of the third expression.

I'd actually maintain that this is not the clearest wording, but when compared to similar wording in e.g. the rules for the built-in subscript operator (which doesn't return a reference type, but its result is "the value" referred to by its two operands), it does seem unambiguous enough that the whole expression here "*is*" one of the original strings.

Comment: I'd be tempted to add to `[expr.cond/5]` something like the wording for the [built-in] dereference operator (which is along the lines of "the result is an lvalue referring to the original object"), to make this super-explicit.

Comment: _I'd actually maintain that this is not the clearest wording_ Should be smth like `s/value/result/`. Plus "(possible-converted) expression"

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Possibly. It seems to me that the wording was never really properly revisited since C with more complex user-defined types in mind (as it makes more sense for built-ins and trivially copyables). I'm tempted to write an editorial proposal... but since I seem to be the only one in the world struggling with these definitions, that might just be a waste of everyone's time. :)

Comment: _I seem to be the only one in the world struggling with these definitions_ I don't think so.

Comment: The wording in the standard is highly stilted and exacting.  It's one of the reasons I hung up my language lawyer spurs.  And the WG21 doesn't do that to show off their superior language skills; they agonize over the exact wording, and work and re-work, and re-re-work it until they are happy with it... and they still have to come out with TRs to fix things.  A painful, arduous process.

Comment: @Eljay Indeed. For what it's worth, I feel they generally get wording right in that sense (although my opinion on the complexity of the language itself deviates from that statement), and my prior heavy activity on [tag:language-lawyer] under a different name I think bears that out. But IMO this not one of those cases. I'd wager that this particular wording hasn't changed in a long, long time. We should be using `std::variant` anyway, right? 

Answer (score 4):

From the very section you quote:

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

The second and third operands are both lvalues of type `std::string const`, so the result is an *lvalue* of type `std::string const`.

> Initialising a `std::string` from a `std::string` involves a copy.

But we're not initializing a `std::string` from a `std::string`. In:

```
const std::string& foo(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    return (s1.size() < s2.size() ? s1 : s2);
}
```

We're initializing a `std::string const&` from an lvalue of type `std::string const`. That's just a direct reference binding. No copy necessary.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I suspect that if you went back and re-read this answer with an open mind you’d understand how it answers your original question. There isn’t really anything else to be said beyond restating what Barry’s already explained.

Comment: @Sneftel My mind is very open. Of course it is? I've literally come here, stating that I have clearly misunderstood something, and asked the community to help me to understand it correctly. But this answer really just makes assertions and says I'm wrong, which has not achieved that goal, sorry. In particular Barry has not explained _why_ _"we're not initialising a `string` from a `string`"_, when I've listed standard rules that appear to suggest we are. I _know_ I'm wrong; I'm asking _why_. He hasn't actually explained anything, so hopefully someone can come along with an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Barry, wait. Forget about the fact that we're about to return from foo. The question is, really, whether "the result" of a ternary operator, as described in the snippets @AsteroidsWithWings quoted, is "officially realized", or whether it may be elided. If it's the former, then it seems we are initializing a `string`. If it isn't, we're just initializing a `const string&`.

Comment: _We're initializing a `std::string const&` from an lvalue of type `std::string const`_ I don't think so. The wording in [stmt.return] is clearly broken. It says: _the `return` statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from the operand_, which is would be nonsensical if we apply this wording here. The result of `foo` invocation is just the result of `return`'s operand. Nothing is (copy-)initialized.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer What's "clearly broken" or "nonsensical" about that? We're copy-initializing a `std::string const&` from the operand - and initializing an lvalue reference from a reference-compatible lvalue is just direct binding [dcl.init.ref].

Comment: [expr.call]/9: _«The result of a function call is the result of the possibly-converted operand of the return statement that transferred control out of the called function»_. [stmt.return]: _«the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call»_. So together these 2 pieces of wording say that the return statement initializes its result from its result. Yes, this change to [expr.call]/9 is relatively recent and made [stmt.return] even more broken than it was before. But this is because it has already been broken.

Comment: I think [stmt.return] should say that `return e;` determines the conversions applied to its operand `e` as-if `e` was an argument in an imaginary function call with the corresponding parameter of the function's return type, ignoring temporary materialization conversion if `e` is a prvalue and the function's return type is the same as the type of `e`, ignoring cv-qualifiers. But the operand only imaginary initializes something. "Function returns a reference" is a colloquial terminology, strictly speaking we don't pass or return references, so we don't need to initialize any reference here.

Comment: But a more simpler argument would be: the result of a glvalue is an object or function denoted by the glvalue. "initializes glvalue result" can't mean "initializes a/the reference", by definition.